# why file json isn't read by the program?

Tags: jquery, json, arbor.js

Hi i don't understand why if i write in the variable the json is right:

```
var theUI  = {
"nodes":{"progetto 1":{"color":"red", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1},
"demos":{"color":"#b2b19d", shape:"dot", "alpha":1},
"halfviz":{"color":"#a7af00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"atlas":{"color":"#a7af00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"echolalia":{"color":"#a7af00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"docs":{"color":"#b2b19d", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1},
"reference":{"color":"#922E00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"introduction":{"color":"#922E00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"code":{"color":"#b2b19d", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1},
"github":{"color":"orange", "alpha":0, "link":""},
".zip":{"color":"orange", "alpha":0, "link":""},
".tar.gz":{"color":"orange", "alpha":0, "link":""}
},
"edges":{
"progetto 1":{
"demos":{"length":.8},
"docs":{"length":.8},
"code":{"length":.8}
},
"demos":{"halfviz":{},
"atlas":{},
"echolalia":{}
},
"docs":{"reference":{},
"introduction":{}
},
"code":{".zip":{},
".tar.gz":{},
"github":{}
}
}
}
var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem()
sys.parameters({stiffness:900, repulsion:2000, gravity:true, dt:0.015})
sys.renderer = Renderer("#sitemap")
sys.graft(theUI)
var nav = Nav("#nav")
$(sys.renderer).bind('navigate', nav.navigate)
$(nav).bind('mode', sys.renderer.switchMode)
nav.init()
})
```

while if I give the data from a file json, the program doesn't work:

```
var theUI  = $.getJSON("data.json")


var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem()
sys.parameters({stiffness:900, repulsion:2000, gravity:true, dt:0.015})
sys.renderer = Renderer("#sitemap")
sys.graft(theUI)
var nav = Nav("#nav")
$(sys.renderer).bind('navigate', nav.navigate)
$(nav).bind('mode', sys.renderer.switchMode)
nav.init()
})
```

it do the get and read the json but the program doesn't work.

The file data.json is this:

```
{
"nodes":{"progetto 1":{"color":"red", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1},
"demos":{"color":"#b2b19d", shape:"dot", "alpha":1},
"halfviz":{"color":"#a7af00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"atlas":{"color":"#a7af00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"echolalia":{"color":"#a7af00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"docs":{"color":"#b2b19d", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1},
"reference":{"color":"#922E00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"introduction":{"color":"#922E00", "alpha":0, "link":""},
"code":{"color":"#b2b19d", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1},
"github":{"color":"orange", "alpha":0, "link":""},
".zip":{"color":"orange", "alpha":0, "link":""},
".tar.gz":{"color":"orange", "alpha":0, "link":""}
},
"edges":{
"progetto 1":{
"demos":{"length":.8},
"docs":{"length":.8},
"code":{"length":.8}
},
"demos":{"halfviz":{},
"atlas":{},
"echolalia":{}
},
"docs":{"reference":{},
"introduction":{}
},
"code":{".zip":{},
".tar.gz":{},
"github":{}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use callback function like this -

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function (theUI) {
    var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem();
    sys.parameters({
        stiffness: 900,
        repulsion: 2000,
        gravity: true,
        dt: 0.015
    });
    sys.renderer = Renderer("#sitemap");
    sys.graft(theUI);
    var nav = Nav("#nav");
    $(sys.renderer).bind('navigate', nav.navigate);
    $(nav).bind('mode', sys.renderer.switchMode);
    nav.init();
});
```

Also,

jsonlint test : http://jsonlint.com/

```
Parse error on line 9:
...2b19d",            shape: "dot",      
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a syntax error in your JSON:

```
SyntaxError: test.json: Unexpected token s
```

second line:

```
"demos":{"color":"#b2b19d", shape:"dot", "alpha":1},
```

`shape` should be quoted.

Remember that in JSON all keys and string values must be quoted with double quotes in order to have a valid JSON

EDIT: I feel like a compiler now. :D

Because you have the next syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: test.json: Unexpected token .
```

and this two times is in the following lines:

```
"demos":{"length":.8},
"docs":{"length":.8},
"code":{"length":.8}
```

`.8` is not a valid value JSON. Use `0.8`

That should be it now and you are good to go.

Comment: Ok thank you very much i havn't seen it, but also with the correction the result is the same unluckily...